# Apple WatchOS 2 native SOAP web service call in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am trying to call SOAP web service from watchOS 2 natively. I have read to apple document on WatchOS 2 and found that it can be possible with NSURLSession but documents are not very useful to find how? I have found some good help in swift but not for Objective c.

Can anyone help me to writing Objective c code for calling SOAP Web Service with basic apache authentication directly form WatchOS 2 using NSURLSession and read response. Is there any good API available to call SOAP Wen service which can be used with WatchOS 2 natively.

Thanks in Advance!